# my json codes work fine but when add Glide for parsing images app force stope

Tags: java, json, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-glide

app read data with J son from server and show that data in card view and all things work fine .but i want add image and read image from server to in card view . use Glide library for do this but when add this library my app become to force stop . here is my code :

MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ArrayList<AndroidVersion> data;
    private DataAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_page);
        initViews();
    }
    private void initViews(){
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        loadJSON();
    }
    private void loadJSON(){
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://memaraneha.ir/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        RequestInterface request = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
        Call<JSONResponse> call = request.getJSON();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponse> call, Response<JSONResponse> response) {

                JSONResponse jsonResponse = response.body();
                data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getAndroid()));
                adapter = new DataAdapter(data);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JSONResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("Error",t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

JSONResponse:

```
public class JSONResponse {
    private AndroidVersion[] android;

    public AndroidVersion[] getAndroid() {
        return android;
    }
}
```

DataAdapter:

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<AndroidVersion> android;


    public DataAdapter(ArrayList<AndroidVersion> android) {
        this.android = android;
    }


    @Override
    public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_row, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DataAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

        viewHolder.tv_name.setText(android.get(i).getName());
        viewHolder.tv_version.setText(android.get(i).getVer());
        viewHolder.tv_api_level.setText(android.get(i).getApi());


        // load image into imageview using glide
        Glide.with(context).load("http://memaraneha.ir/Erfan/images/"+android.get(i).getPic())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.truiton)
                .error(R.drawable.truiton)
                .into(viewHolder.tv_image);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return android.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView tv_name,tv_version,tv_api_level;
        public ImageView tv_image;
        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            tv_name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            tv_version = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_version);
            tv_api_level = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_api_level);
            tv_image= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);

        }
    }

}
```

AndroidVersion:

```
public class AndroidVersion {
    private String ver;
    private String name;
    private String api;
    private String pic;

    public String getVer() {
        return ver;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getApi() {
        return api;
    }
    public String getPic(){
        return pic;
    }
}
```

RequestInterface:

```
public interface RequestInterface {

    @GET("Erfan/ret.php")
    Call<JSONResponse> getJSON();
}
```

card_row.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_name"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_version"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_api_level"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

main_page.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/card_recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and this my json :

```
{ "android": 
[ 
{ "ver": "1.5", "name": "Cupcake", "api": "API level 3","pic":"pic1.jpg" }, 
{ "ver": "1.6", "name": "Donut", "api": "API level 4","pic":"pic2.jpg" }, 
{ "ver": "2.0 - 2.1", "name": "Eclair", "api": "API level 5 - 7","pic":"pic3.jpg" },
{ "ver": "2.2", "name": "Froyo", "api": "API level 8","pic":"pic4.jpg" }, 
{ "ver": "2.3", "name": "Gingerbread", "api": "API level 9 - 10","pic":"pic5.jpg" },
{ "ver": "3.0 - 3.2", "name": "Honeycomb", "api": "API level 11 - 13","pic":"pic6.jpg" }, 
{ "ver": "4.0", "name": "Ice Cream Sandwich", "api": "API level 14 - 15","pic":"pic7.jpg" }, 
{ "ver": "4.1 - 4.3", "name": "JellyBean", "api": "API level 16 - 18","pic":"pic8.jpg" }, 
{ "ver": "4.4", "name": "KitKat", "api": "API level 19","pic":"pic9.jpg" },
{ "ver": "5.0 - 5.1", "name": "Lollipop", "api": "API level 21 - 22","pic":"pic10.jpg" }, 
{ "ver": "6.0", "name": "Marshmallow", "api": "API level 23","pic":"pic11.jpg" } 
] 
}
```

i think my problem is in Data Adapter when add Glide ... if some one can please help me

Comment: Add your log or exception

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:cannot start a load on a null Context
com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.get(RequestManagerRetriever.java:83)
com.bumptech.glide.Glide.with(Glide.java:609)
com.exampleret.DataAdapter.onBindViewHolder(DataAdapter.java:44)
                                                                  com.example.ret.DataAdapter.onBindViewHolder(DataAdapter.java:19)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your adapter's Constructor and pass `Context` to it. As your log shows, `Glide` want to access to `Context` but it's **not** initialized.

```
  public DataAdapter(Contenxt context,ArrayList<AndroidVersion> android) {
        this.context = context;
        this.android = android;
    }
```

initialize your adapter with:

```
adapter = new DataAdapter(MainActivity.this,data);
```

Comment: @erfan your wellcome ;)